# Non-nullable error with GraphQL doesn't give much detail which might allow me to investigate

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm getting this error in a node application I'm trying to use:

```
{ [GraphQLError: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Issue.id.]
  message: 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field Issue.id.',
  locations: [ { line: 3, column: 9 } ],
  path: [ 'issueList', 0, 'id' ],
  extensions:
   { code: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR',
     exception: { stacktrace: [Array] } } }
```

I assume I'm passing a null ID in my query but the field `Issue.id` expects a value.

Unfortunately there is nothing else in the error so I don't know where to begin looking into it. How do I fix this?

Comment: It seems your API response is returning `null` for `Issue.id`, so check your API response logic.

Comment: Can you please show your resolver configuration for `Issue`, like where the mappings is between the resolver and the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was pointing to the wrong database. `Issue.id` did not even exist in the database I pointed to.